# Error: incompatible provider version Terraform v1.60.0

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Hello I'm newbie for terraform, I started using terraform official documentation, but I'm facing an issue with in `terraform init`

getting an error like this.

```
Initializing the backend...

Initializing provider plugins...
- Checking for available provider plugins...

Provider {"aws"} v1.60.0 is not compatible with Terraform 0.12.15.

Provider version 2.7.0 is the earliest compatible version. Select it with
the following version constraint:

        version = "~> 2.7"

Terraform checked all of the plugin versions matching the given constraint:
    ~> 1.7

Consult the documentation for this provider for more information on
compatibility between provider and Terraform versions.


Error: incompatible provider version
```

How to fix it this issue.
terraform version

```
C:\terraform>terraform -v
Terraform v0.12.15
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working as expected, you'll need to upgrade the AWS provider.

> It is recommended to use version constraints when configuring Terraform providers.

Add a line in your provider configuration like below:

```
provider "aws" {
  # ... other configuration ...

  version = "~> 2.7"
}
```

> If you are following that recommendation, update the version constraints in your Terraform configuration and run terraform init to download the new version.

There is a caveat about upgrading to the latest 1.X version before upgrading to 2.x.  See the upgrade reference below for instructions.

**References**

[Provider "aws" v1.60.0 is not compatible with Terraform 0.12.3](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/21927)
[AWS Provider Version 2 Upgrade Guide](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/guides/version-2-upgrade.html)